# Sort Objects in a Set

Tags: java, collections, compare

Suppose I have a Employee class

```
Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    Date DOB;
}
```

I create 100 objects and put them in Set, but want them sorted on DOB today, and some other day on name, and some other day on id .
I can create three Comparators, but not sure where should I pass these comparators, as Collections.sort takes List as 1st param.
**Is TreeSet (accepts Comparator as Constructor) the only solution ?**

Comment: Show us your research.  *Plenty* of Google hits for your question title:  [hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=sort+objects+in+set&aq=f&oq=sort+objects+in+set&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j0l2j60.1517&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: By construction, a HashSet, for example, is not sorted. So applying a `sort` method on it does not make much sense. Your main options: store the data in a list then sort or store them in a TreeSet.

Comment: @assylias - OP mentioned `TreeSet`, but not `HashSet`. I think OP already knows to use a `Set` implementation that supports ordering. A `TreeSet` is still a `Set`.

Comment: @djechlin i think you missed my question "Is TreeSet (accepts Comparator as Constructor) the only solution ?" anyway its how you see

Comment: Use of TreeSet is probably the most obvious and simplest solution. It's certainly not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` is a set that's always sorted according to some comparator. So you could have three different sets, with each their own comparator.

Answer (score 0):

`Set`s don't have order. They're like math sets.

If you want an order, you need a `List`, for example. Then you can sort them, or give them any order you want.

You should create a `List` from that `Set` you have, and then apply the `Comparator` you want. If you want to re-sort them, just apply `sort()` again, with a different `Comparator`.